# How do I remove duplicated values in pandas and replace those with an empty value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove duplicate values in pandas and replace those values with an empty value.

Originally, I had those A values on Header A (Column A) and I would like remove those A values and replace A with an empty string ""

| Header A | Header B |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| A | D |
| A | E |
| A | F |

To this:

| Header A | Header B |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
|  | C |
|  | D |
|  | E |
|  | F |

How do I do this in Pandas using Python?
Those values are from csv file.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df.loc[df['Header A'].duplicated(), 'Header A'] = ''
print (df)
  Header A Header B
0        A        B
1                 C
2                 D
3                 E
4                 F
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Replace with NaN:

```
df.loc[df['Header A'].duplicated(), 'Header A'] = np.NaN
```

#### Replace with empty string:

```
df.loc[df['Header A'].duplicated(), 'Header A'] = ""
```

#### if you want it another columns as well:

```
df.loc[(df['Header A'].duplicated() & df['Header B'].duplicated()), ['Header A','Header B']] = ''
```